# How to access implicit objects in my templates

Tags: servlets, view, playframework, httprequest

I want to know what is the current url of my template. I have read [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/templates#implicits) that the "request" is an implicit object present in all templates which returns the url of my template.

So I have tried this:

**Controllers:**

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return redirect("/home");
    }

    public static Result home() {
        return ok(homePage.render());
    }

    public static Result aboutUs() {
        return ok(aboutUs.render());
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

leftbar.scala.html file:

```
<aside id="left-panel">
  <nav>
     <ul class="animated fadeInLeft"> 
       <li class="@if(request.uri.contains("/aboutus")){active}">(some code here)</li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
</aside>
```

homePage.scala.html file:

```
@scripts = { (some scripts here) }
@views.html.main("Beta Project", scripts) {

    @views.html.leftbar()

    <div id="main" role="main">
        <div id="content">
            <span><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>SOMETHING</span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Where I import the leftbar.scala.html file I get this error:

> not found: value request

What should I do to solve this error? Thanks in advance

Comment: You linked Play 1.2.4 docs. Is that what you're using? Or are you using Play 2.x? You should include more code to give someone a chance at solving this problem. At a minimum, you should include the view parameters you tried.

Comment: I have already edited my post. Since now, sorry about lack of information. How can I know if am i using Play 2.x or another thing? Sorry i'm a begginer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more code from your template would be useful, but you can probably fix it by adding

```
(implicit request: Request[AnyContent])
```

at the end of the first line on your template.

Comment: I did just put this part of code because it's a simple template with <ul> and <li>. If you think it's better I can put all code. I have tried with that you suggested but when I "call" this template in another page, this ask me an httpRequest. What should I put in 'AnyContent' ?

Comment: It's easier for other people to understand your problem if you give complete examples of a minimal working problem. So snippet of controller,  including page and the actual template so we can see what your doing.